# Merging Maps using `aggregate`

Tags: scala, dictionary, parallel-processing, aggregate, scala-collections

For any given collection of `Map`, for instance,

```
val in = Array( Map("a" -> 1,  "b" -> 2),
                Map("a" -> 11, "c" -> 4),
                Map("b" -> 7,  "c" -> 10))
```

how to use `aggregate` on `in.par` so as to merge the maps into

```
Map ( "a" -> 12, "b" -> 9, "c" -> 14 )
```

Note `Map` merging has been asked multiple times, yet looking for a solution with `aggregate` on parallel collections.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about applying merge as both `seqop` and `comboop`?

```
val in = Array(
  Map("a" -> 1,  "b" -> 2),
  Map("a" -> 11, "c" -> 4),
  Map("b" -> 7,  "c" -> 10)
)

def merge(m1: Map[String, Int], m2: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Int] =
  m1 ++ m2.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + m1.getOrElse(k, 0)) }

in.par.aggregate(Map[String, Int]())(merge, merge)
```

**Update**

You pass to `aggregate` initial accumulator value(empty map) and two closures - `seqop` and `comboop`.

Parallel sequence splits in several partitions to be processed in parallel. Each partition is processed by successively applying `seqop` to accumulator and array element.

```
def seqop(
    accumulator: Map[String, Int], 
    element: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Int] = merge(accumulator, element)
```

`seqop` takes initial accumulator value and first array element and merges it. Next it takes previous result and next array element and so on until whole partition is merged in one map.

When every partition is merged in a separate map, these maps should be combined by applying `comboop`. `comboop` takes merged map from first partition and merged map from second partition and merges it together. Next it takes previous result and map from third partition and so on until all is merged in one map. This is the result of `aggregate`.

```
def comboop(
    m1: Map[String, Int], 
    m2: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Int] = merge(m1, m2)
```

It is just coincidence that `seqop` and `comboop` are the same. In general they differs in logic and signatures.

Comment: I've added a small comment, hth.